# Where can I find a transcriptome of a normal uveal melanocyte?

Tags: cell-biology, bioinformatics, transcription

I am looking for a database where I could find a transcriptome (say obtained with a microarray analysis) of one (or ideally many) normal uveal melanocytes ?

Answer (score 1):

I can't find any transcriptome data, but I did find miRNAome data from [GEO at NCBI](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/geo/query/acc.cgi?acc=GSE18381) and [Array Express at EMBL](http://www.ebi.ac.uk/arrayexpress/browse.html?keywords=uveal%20melanocytes).